# Custom syntax highlighting for Visual Studio 2012 and .less source files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, syntax-highlighting, less

We use .less files (compiled using simplyLess or WinLess) to generate .css files. Visual Studio 2012 doesn't have syntax highlighting for .less files. I know that I can create a .hlx file in the \msdev\bin\ide folder that will handle syntax highlighting for this extension.

I'm wondering if anyone has already done this and there is an existing .hlx file out there?

thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [Web Essentials extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Web Essentials extension causes a lot of hangups, and errant auto-complete, reformatting on paste and other issues for me in VS2012... as of this comment's date.

Comment: @Tracker1: I've never had any such problems.  http://madskristensen.net/contact.aspx?subject=Web%20Essentials%202012%20bug

Comment: Then you are lucky... I've had a lot of issues with nested elements, pasting etc in less files causing a reformat of rules above, and sometimes adding/intellisense/auto-completing things I wasn't touching.